# How can I get my current mouse position in pyautogui?

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

So I was making an autotyper but I got stuck i want to find the current location of my mouse (on the search box) so that my program can click on the text box, but i cannot figure out how to get my current mouse X and Y. Any help is accepted!

Here is my code

```
import pyautogui


def autotyper():
    pyautogui.click("textbox") # how can i get my current mouse x and y to put here?
    pyautogui.write("text to search")
    pyautogui.press("enter")

autotyper()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This function will give you the current X and Y position of your mouse, basically, wherever your mouse is hovering right now it will give you its X, and Y on the screen.

```
pyautogui.position()
```